# React code to display date in Formatted Way and limit future dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-hooks, use-state

In REact I am having a state variable like this

```
    const [ dob, setDob ] = useState();
```

and in the jsx I am having like this

```
<input type="date" max="new Date()" value = {dob} onChange={(e)=>setDov(e.target.value)}/>
```

I am facing two issues

1. I am unable to limit future dates i.e all the dates after today cant be selected but when I am giving max attribute as  I am unable to limit the future date

```
new Date() or new Date().getTime()
```

2. I need to show the date after selection in this format DD/MM/YYYY I am unable to display the converted date.For it I tried modyifying the onChange() as onChange()=>setDob(new Date(e.target.value.tolocaleTimestring()))
   But still its not working. I am getting error toLocaleString() is not a function

**Notes:- I am using React and purely functional components**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the MDN docs for date type and constraining the inputs, you can use `min` and `max` attributes on input. So what you did is right except passing a string to max. It needs to be a string (parsable to date) or date object I think.

e.g.

```html
<input type="date" max={new Date()} value = {dob} onChange={(e)=>setDov(e.target.value)}/>
```

Refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/HTML5_input_types#constraining_datetime_values for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple error/problem in the code:

1- You can't add JS code in html variable, the HTML `max` property accept texts. and another issue you had there (event if max accepts JS expression) is that `new Date ()` dosen't match the format it accepts, you have to convert it **ISO standard** i.e. `new Date().toISOString()`.

2- I am not sure whats the issue you are facing here, belwo I added a snippest that worked for me, that resolved both (1 and 2).

```
const [ dob, setDob ] = useState();
 const today = new Date().toISOString();
  return (
    <div >
   <input type="date" max={today} value = {dob} onChange={(e)=>setDob(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: For my second issue From the Date picker When I select the date in the input field should be like  DD/MM/YYYY But currently, when I select the date from the input it is coming as dd-mm-yyyy.If I could get that that would be helpful for me

Comment: When I tested the code sinppest I got it as "DD/MM/YYYY", so it might be a browser issue, or somethingl ike that.